# In C, does assigning a struct to a struct pointer assigns a copied value of the struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dereference

I just started learning C so pardon me if the nomenclature is incorrect.

If I assign a `struct` to a `struct pointer` and then change values of struct, it's not reflected when I try to access the value from `struct pointer`.

```
struct Node_int *new_node_address = (struct Node_int *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node_int));
struct Node_int new_node_instance;
*new_node_address = new_node_instance;
new_node_instance.data = data;
new_node_instance.next= NULL;
printf("%d", new_node_address->data)
```

Here `printf("%d", new_node_address->data)` will return a garbage value but same print statement in following code will return correct/assigned data.

```
struct Node_int *new_node_address = (struct Node_int *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node_int));
struct Node_int new_node_instance;
new_node_instance.data = data;
new_node_instance.next= NULL;
*new_node_address = new_node_instance;
printf("%d", new_node_address->data)
```

I want to understand why this is happening. Does `*new_node_address` gets the copied value of `new_node_instance` in the memory?

Comment: *"If I assign a struct to a struct pointer"* - that isn't what you're doing. `*new_node_address = new_node_instance;` assigns a struct to a struct. The dereference operator applied to the pointer sees to that. All you're changing is the order in the first vs second samples. The latter blasts over the members you just set with indeterminate data from `new_node_instance` (because it was never initialized).

Comment: In the code you show, `new_node_instance` is never initialized, so `*new_node_address = new_node_instance;` does not set anything in `new_node_address` to definite values, so why would you expect any particular value? If we are supposed to know that `new_node_instance` has been set to something, show that. Edit the code to show a [mre]. Include a copy of the exact output you observe. Do not just describe it as “a garbage value”; show the exact output. And do not just describe output as “correct/assigned data”; show the exact output.

Comment: The title in itself contains an error, since assigning always have to be to the same type: either assigning a pointer to a struct s to a pointer to a struct s or assign a struct-instance to same type struct instance. Which helps to derive the answer: First one would be the "pointing" to a address (regardless if this adress is valid), second one would be the shallow member copy you can expect in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to understand why this is happening. Does `*new_node_address` gets the copied value of `new_node_instance` in the memory?*

Yes, it does, there is a copy, the dereference operator `*` means you are copying data to the memory address which is pointed by `new_node_address`. Which is the memory block returned by `malloc`.

If you want to make the pointer point to the address of the declared `new_node_instance`, you'd need:

```
new_node_address = &new_node_instance;
```

In this case no copy takes place and for that reason you also don't need to allocate memory, you are making the pointer point to a variable which already has memory storage.

The reason why the second code snippet works is because you make the copy after you assign the data, as opposed to the first code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it seems there is a typo

```
new_node_instance.data = data;
new_node_instance.data= NULL;
```

that is there is used the same data member `data`. It seems that the second data member is named something like `next` or `link`.

> If I assign a struct to a struct pointer and then change values of
> struct, it's not reflected when I try to access the value from struct
> pointer.

It is because the pointer points to another separate object that was allocated dynamically.

You need at first to assign values to the object `new_node_instance` and then assign the object of the structure type to the dynamically allocated object as for example

```
new_node_instance.data = data;
new_node_instance.next = NULL;

*new_node_address = new_node_instance;
```

or

```
struct Node_int new_node_instance = { .data = data, .next = NULL };
*new_node_address = new_node_instance;
```

That is in the assignment of objects of structure types values of data members are copied.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I corrected it.